# CoxPHFitter: The input must have at least 3 entries

Tags: pandas, statsmodels, cox-regression

I am trying to run `lifelines`' CoxPHFitter (python3) and i get this value error:

> The input must have at least 3 entries!

i've read the function it connects to at  stats but im not sure how to imply the error to the data i have so i could run it propely.
anybody wants to try with my data?

THE CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter
Table=pd.read_csv(...)
Table['Duration']=Table['FAILURE_DATE']-Table['INSTALL_DATE']#creating 
 duration column
'''
making all durations positive
'''
Table = Table[~Table['Duration'].isnull()]

newB = []
for item in Table['Duration']:
    item_v = item
    if not isinstance(item,str) and item<0:
        item_v = abs(item)
    newB.append(item_v)

Table.loc[:, 'Duration'] = newB

'''
marking if 'death' occured 
'''
newC = []
for item in Table['InService']:
    if item==1:
        item_v = 0
    else:
        item_v = 1
    newC.append(item_v)

Table.loc[:,'watched'] = newC

cph = CoxPHFitter()

cols_to_transform = ['col1','col2',... ]
'''
creating dummy variables instead of categorical data
'''
dummies = pd.get_dummies( Table, columns = cols_to_transform )


cph.fit(dummies, 'Duration', 'watched')
cph.print_summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

That problem happens in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py#L412, which lifelines uses as a pre-fitting check. According to the code, the input must have atleast length 3. However, it appears in your case it doesn't. What is the `shape` of your `dummies` variable? I believe the problem is there.